Gravitee : How to change request status code
Is it possible to rewrite the status code from a response?
My backend service returns a 202, but the requester only accepts 200 as an actual success.
Because of that, I want to rewrite the response status code from 202 to 200.
I tried the Mocking policy, but that one will not call the backend services.
I also tried the Groovy Policy in the following way:
if(response.status == 202) {
  result.state = State.SUCCESS;
  result.code = 200
  result.error = '{"message":"ok"}'
  result.contentType = 'application/json'
}

But that one also gives me the original 202 http status code.

It is currently a little flaw of the Groovy Policy.
To override the status code, you will need to change
result.state = State.SUCCESS;

to:
result.state = State.FAILURE;

But be careful because it will interrupt the response flow: it will be the last action executed.
Have a good day!

Thank you. I guess I should write a bug report to them.
